# TableView Not Working Properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My problem is when I scroll tableview its not working properly.

For example I have 2 section And in section 0 I'm using profile image in cell and in section 1 I'm hiding them but when I scroll down and up images are losing. also I have a variable and when its ok I'm changing second image. But when I scroll its changing image but when I scroll down its changing that images which is equal to indexpath.

You can find images in here

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserTableViewCell
    if self.itemInfo.title == "USERNAME" && indexPath.section == 0 {
        let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
        let friendImage = UIImage(named: "SearchPeopleAdded")
        for friend in self.friends {
            if friend.objectId == user.objectId {
                cell.groupAddImageView.image = friendImage
                cell.selectionStyle = .None
                cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        }

        cell.nameLabel!.text = user["username"] as? String

        if let image = user["avatar_image"] as? PFFile {
            cell.userImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: image.url!))
        }

    }else if itemInfo.title == "ADDRESSBOOK" && indexPath.section == 1 {
        if isSearchActive == false {
            let person = contacts[indexPath.row]
            var firstName = person.name?.firstName
            var lastName = person.name?.lastName

            if firstName == nil || lastName == nil {
                if firstName == nil {
                    firstName = ""
                }
                if lastName == nil {
                    lastName = ""
                }
                if firstName == nil && lastName == nil {
                    if person.phones![0].number != nil {
                        firstName = person.phones![0].number
                        lastName = ""
                    }else {
                        firstName = ""
                        lastName = ""
                    }
                }
            }
            let fullName: String = firstName! + " " + lastName!
            cell.nameLabel.text = fullName
            cell.userImageView.hidden = true
        }else {
            let person = filteredAddressBookUsers[indexPath.row]
            var firstName = person.name?.firstName
            var lastName = person.name?.lastName

            if firstName == nil || lastName == nil {
                if firstName == nil {
                    firstName = ""
                    print("first name nil")
                }
                if lastName == nil {
                    lastName = ""
                    print("last name nil")
                }
                if firstName == nil && lastName == nil {
                    print("both nil")
                    if person.phones![0].number != nil {
                        firstName = person.phones![0].number
                        lastName = ""
                    }else {
                        firstName = ""
                        lastName = ""
                    }

                }
            }
            let fullName: String = firstName! + " " + lastName!
            cell.nameLabel.text = fullName
            cell.userImageView.hidden = true
        }
    }else if self.itemInfo.title == "ADDRESSBOOK" && indexPath.section == 0 {
        let user = self.addressMatchedUsers[indexPath.row]

        let friendImage = UIImage(named: "SearchPeopleAdded")
        for friend in self.friends {
            if friend.objectId == user.objectId {
                cell.groupAddImageView.image = friendImage
                cell.selectionStyle = .None
                cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        }

        cell.nameLabel!.text = user["username"] as? String

        if let image = user["avatar_image"] as? PFFile {
            cell.userImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: image.url!))
        }
    }
    //configure(cell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Add the whole code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: let user = self.users[**indexPath.row**] here instead of indexPath.row you should do indexPath.section as you are having sectional tableView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `UITableViewCell` subclass and override `prepeareForReuse` function - to turn cell to default/required mode.

Swift:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    //set cell to initial/required state here 
}
```

> Prepares a reusable cell for reuse by the table view's delegate.
>
> If a `UITableViewCell` object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the `UITableVie`w method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.